2.4.5 Purchase Order Invocing - Not showing
Newbie - do not know anything about webpage development but my company has been using Magento forever and we had an older version. Some of our customer pay with purchase order since updating to the 2.4.5 version the invoice option does not show up when there are purchase orders. I am attaching a picture of my view, the order is scrunched up to the left and there are minimal options, the only order status showing is pending and I am not able to close out the order. These customers pay with check monthly, or we run their cards off the website, or they pay upon pick up, ect. On the right-hand side top section, I do not show Hold, Invoice, Ship options only the ones listed. How can I make this order look like all other order and include the invoice option so when the order is complete, I generate the invoice and can close the order out? Or even add info for shipping.
I Should add that I am only on the backen of the website and do not even know where I would edit any code so if anyone has step by step instructions on how to do it without code even better!! Thanks!!

It seems like the upgrade conflicts with a custom code in your project.
As a temporary workaround while you get a developer to track down the bug, I suggest (if it works) using the orders grid view mass actions to do some basic actions like printing the invoice(s).
(also, try other browsers, cleaning the cache, private navigation)
As a comment: can you provide the previous version?
